# Overwriting a property on a HTMLVideoElement to a getter/setter with custom logic

Tags: javascript, youtube, getter-setter

### What I want to accomplish:

I'm trying to write an extension for chrome that adds some extra functionality to Youtube. This particular problem has to do with knowing when the playback rate has been changed by the user (which can be done by clicking the settings icon, then speed).

### What I've tried to do:

I'm trying to do this by replacing the "playbackRate" property on the HTMLVideoElement with a getter/setter object so that I can detect when this happens.

### The Problem:

When the user changes it, all my logic runs, however the video will no longer actually change speed.

### The Code:

```
    let videoObj = document.getElementsByTagName('video')[0];
    let storePlaybackRate = videoObj.playbackRate;
    Object.defineProperty(videoObj,'playbackRate',{
        get(){return storePlaybackRate;},
        set(val){
            storePlaybackRate = val;
            console.log("Updated Value: ",val);

            //Custom Logic that does work.

            return val;
        }
    });
```

To test this just paste the code into the console on any youtube video, then change playback speed. The console.log happens, but the video no longer changes speed.

### Things I already checked

1.That this property is not already a getter/setter object that I'm overwriting. This is checked via:

```
Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(videoObj, 'playbackRate');
```

2.I thought maybe it was because I wasn't returning the new value in the setter, but that wasn't it.

### Final Summary

I understand there are other ways of doing what I'm trying to do, and so if this is impossible by this method, that's fine. But I just really wanted to understand why this doesn't work. Or if I made an error.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are overwriting an inherited getter/setter.

An HTMLVideoElement does not have its own getter/setter for playbackRate, but inherits one from HTMLMediaElement.prototype. Thats why `Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(video,'playbackRate')` returns `undefined`

To overwrite it, you have to store the original descriptor, and call them within your own descriptor.

```
originalDescriptor = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(HTMLMediaElement.prototype, 'playbackRate');

Object.defineProperty(HTMLVideoElement.prototype,'playbackRate',{
    set:function(value){
        originalDescriptor.set.call(this,value);
        console.log('value changed',value);
    },
    get:originalDescriptor.get
});
```

I've used the prototype for the video in this example, it is possible to adjust the descriptor for a specific element by replacing `HTMLVideoElement.prototype` with the video element's reference.

Comment: Thank you a million, this was the first time I had tried to use getters/setters, and I understand you have to call the original if there was one already. My only question left is how would I have found the original getter without just knowing that HTMLVideoElement inherits one from HTMLMediaElement? Is there a similar method to Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor that helped you find that? Or just research?

Comment: Actually, I understand. Just incase anyone comes across this and is trying to figure it out.  I thought if Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor returns undefined, that just meant it wasn't a getter/setter, but that actually will always return something, unless the property is inherited. So because I got undefined, it shows I can just check the ___proto of the element, until I find the first instance of the property.   If I have any of that wrong, please correct me.  Thanks again. Sorry I somehow didn't figure that out sooner.

Comment: @user1628497, that's correct. `Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor` (like `Object.hasOwnProperty`) only checks for it's own properties.